# Orchard widget h1 and link rendering

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to using orchard and have run into somewhat of a invisible wall..

I have a widget where i need to add a div containing a link tag inside a h1 tag, however the orchard editor accepts this but does not include the h1 or  link tag because there is no text between the tag and thus doe not render what i want.
sample code to insert:

```xml
 <div class="products-div">
    <div class="product-item ">
    <div class="product-item-header motor-insure">
        <h1>
            <a href="/motor-insure-plan">
                <div class="product-item-img">
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-item-header-text">
                    MOTOR <b><i>Insure</i></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Plan                                             </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </a>
        </h1>
    </div>
```

I have tried looking for the h1 field with no luck so as to alter the .cshtml file to render my shape. Would someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you are using the tinymce editor I assume?

Comment: Yes i am using that editor.

Comment: Thank you Hazza. I installed and enabled the CKEditor for orchard and disabled the tinymce editor.